# Access a remote EJB from another EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, remote-access

I'm currently trying to use IIOP to access a remote EJB but cannot make it work. I have two EAR files, which are running on two different machines. Both use Glassfish 4.0 and Java EE 7.

The EJB ExampleSessionBean2 in ExampleEar should invoke the printHello() method of EJB ExampleSessionBean3 in ExampleEar2. The code of these EJBs and their deployment descriptors is the following:

ExampleSessionBean2:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ExampleSessionBean2 implements ExampleSessionBean2Interface {

@EJB(lookup="java:comp/env/ejb/ExampleSessionBean3")
ExampleSessionBean3Interface bean;

 public ExampleSessionBean2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, here Bean2");
        bean.printHello();
    }
```

ExampleSessionBean2 ejb-jar.xml:

```
<display-name>ExampleEJB2</display-name>
   <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
             <ejb-name>ExampleSessionBean2</ejb-name>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
            <ejb-ref>
               <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ExampleSessionBean3</ejb-ref-name>
               <remote>bean.ExampleSessionBean3Interface</remote> 
            </ejb-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
  <ejb-client-jar>ExampleEJB2Client.jar</ejb-client-jar>
```

ExampleSessionBean2 glassfish-ejb-jar.xml:

```
<enterprise-beans>
        <ejb>
        <ejb-name>ExampleSessionBean2</ejb-name>
        <ejb-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ExampleSessionBean3</ejb-ref-name>
            <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:[IP address]:3700#java:global/ExampleEAR2/ExampleEJB3/ExampleSessionBean3!bean.ExampleSessionBean3Interface</jndi-name>
       </ejb-ref>
        </ejb>
     </enterprise-beans>
```

ExampleSessionBean3:

```
@Stateless(name="ExampleSessionBean3")
@LocalBean
public class ExampleSessionBean3 implements ExampleSessionBean3Interface {
```

The ejb-jar.xml and glassfish-ejb-jar.xml are default.

When I call the method printHello() of ExampleSessionBean2, it happens nothing. The status bar for the connection in Eclipse stops at some point. However, there are no exceptions shown. When I use it local, it works.

Further, I tried it with the setting -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=[IP address] as an argument for the VM, but no change.

Is it the right way how I use IIOP to access a remote EJB? Are the annotations an the changes in the descriptors right?

I also have the question whether there are other possibilities to let two EJBs communicate that are NOT in the same Glassfish cluster. For instance, are RessourceAdapters useful for this? Or are there other mechanisms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EJB, Remoting between two application-servers (glassfish)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370559/ejb-remoting-between-two-application-servers-glassfish)

Answer (score 0):

Just on the surface: you are using `@LocalBean` on both beans... the one that is to be accessed remotely (Bean3?) should be annotated as a `@Remote`.

Comment: I tried to annotate it with Remote. However, this did not work either. Furthermore, note that the Bean's interface was already annotated with Remote.